# CollectionView dataSource not working when using UICollectionViewController, but works when using UIViewController with a CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am subclassing a `UICollectionView`, and taking care of its `dataSource`. I assign `dataSource` to `self` during the `init` phase of the CollectionView.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CollectionViewSubclass: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    public override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        dataSource = self
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        dataSource = self
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // This is called for the first case, but not the second

        return 1
    }

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // This is called for the first case, but not the second

        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
}
```

- Case 1: when I use the `CollectionViewSubclass` inside a `UIViewController`, all works well and both `dataSource` methods (`numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAt` are called correctly.
- case 2: when I use a `CollectionViewSubclass` inside a `UICollectionViewController`, for some reason the `dataSource` methods are not called, although when I debugged, I checked that the `init(coder:)` was indeed called and `dataSource = self` got executed. But it seems that somehow, the dataSource got `nil` again at a later stage, and so the `dataSource` methods are not being called.

I can't get my head around that and I tried to debug, but with no avail. Any help to tell me the reason, or to give me ideas to debug that are appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**: When I assign `dataSource = self` after the `init` stage, everything works well. But I would rather do it in the `init` phase. How can I make it work during `init`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `UICollectionViewConrtoller` [docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewcontroller):

> When loading a collection view from a storyboard or nib file, the data source and delegate objects for the collection view are obtained from the nib file. If a data source or delegate is not specified, the collection view controller **assigns itself** to the unspecified role.

So if you use `UICollectionViewConrtoller` you need to reassign dataSource to your custom collection view.

Comment: Very good catch in the doc. but I am assigning the dataSource to my custom collectionView as you can see above. What am I missing? I guess I am doing it in the wrong place? where can I do it in the init phase so that it works? cause it's true that when I do the assignment at a later stage, it works well, but I'd like to assign the dataSource during init phase

Comment: What happens when you use `UICollectionViewConrtoller`: **1.** View controller gets initialized. **2.** Your custom collection view is initialized (at this point `dataSource` is your collection view. **3.** Collection view is getting assigned to view controller - at this point view controller takes over `dataSource`.

Comment: I get your idea that you want to assign datasource on init stage, but that's not a good practice to have a view that configures itself, the main view task is to *display* information and send user events. That's what view controllers are for - configuring the view and being delegates and/or datasources.

Comment: Agreed with you, thanks for all the great explanations!